# registering if a button is pressed

Tags: button, arduino, interrupt

I'm making a code on Arduino that checks if a button is pressed every second, and prints the result out to serial monitor. Every time i push the button it should print "The button is pressed" and every time i release the button it should print "the button is released".

I wrote this code:

```
     volatile boolean buttonPressed = false;

    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      Serial.begin(9600);
      attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2),push,RISING); 
      attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(3),release,FALLING); 

    }

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
       if (buttonPressed = true) {
        Serial.println(" Button is pressed");
      }
      else {
        Serial.println(" Button is not pressed");
      }
      delay(1000);
    }

    void push () {
      buttonPressed = true;
    }
    void release () {
      buttonPressed = false;
    }
```

This code results in the serial monitor constantly printing out "The button is pressed".

I had a friend try and fix it, and now it works perfectly, but I don't understand why. So basically I need someone to explain why the second one works, and the first one does not. Especially the logic behind the `lastState`part.

This is what the working version looks like:

```
volatile boolean pressed = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), push, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(3), release, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  static boolean lastState = pressed;
  if (lastState != pressed) {
    if (pressed == true) {
      Serial.println("Button is pressed");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Button");
    }
    lastState = pressed;
  }
}
void push() {
  pressed = true;
}
void release() {
  pressed = false;
}
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

First: why not ask the friend?

Second: your code: `if (buttonPressed = true)` should be `if (buttonPressed == true)`.
Variable buttonPressed is now always set to true (and not compared).
Anyway, after fixing this, you still have constantly printing *pressed* or *not pressed*.

Third, your friends code:
pressed is set to false, so after entering the loop function, lastState is also set to false. The first if is not executed.
After a push, pressed is set to true, therefore the first if is now executed because lastState is not equal to pressed (false vs true).
After printing, lastState is equal to pressed, and the if is not executed till pressed changes again.